# Selenium output different from browser. can't find table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find the "query results" table on this page: https://dune.com/queries/604672/1128586

using

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep
from random import randint

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36"
headers = {'User-Agent': USER_AGENT}
url="https://dune.com/queries/604672/1128634"
chromedriver_path = "E:\\py\\testsoup\\win\\chromedriver.exe"

service = Service(chromedriver_path)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service,chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
sleep(randint(3, 5))


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()


f = open(".\\url.html", "w", errors="ignore")
f.write(soup.prettify())
f.close()

print(soup.prettify())

table = soup.find("table",{"class":"table_table__fuS_N"})
#df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]

print(table)
```

However I've identified that code in actual browser (brave)
div aria-labelledby="tabs--2-

[image]

Is different than what selenium fetches. selenium doesn't fetch the table tab.
div aria-labelledby="tabs--1-

[image]

any ideas how to get the table?

Comment: the table is not called 'table'. Use beautifulsoup, access first tbody with role rowgroup. and than just scrape all the <tr role='row'>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the following code is working without any issues

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service)
url = 'https://dune.com/queries/604672/1128586'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
table = soup.select_one('table[class="table_table__fuS_N"]')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          first_time  new_users  cumu_users
0   2022-06-24 00:00      13617       13617
1   2022-06-25 00:00      11836       25453
2   2022-06-26 00:00       9381       34834
3   2022-06-27 00:00       7553       42387
4   2022-06-28 00:00       7576       49963
5   2022-06-29 00:00       6988       56951
6   2022-06-30 00:00       6027       62978
7   2022-07-01 00:00       5069       68047
8   2022-07-02 00:00       6908       74955
9   2022-07-03 00:00       5055       80010
10  2022-07-04 00:00       4055       84065
11  2022-07-05 00:00       3914       87979
12  2022-07-06 00:00       3456       91435
13  2022-07-07 00:00       3322       94757
14  2022-07-08 00:00       2589       97346
15  2022-07-09 00:00       2906      100252
16  2022-07-10 00:00       2751      103003
17  2022-07-11 00:00       2890      105893
18  2022-07-12 00:00       2916      108809
19  2022-07-13 00:00       3868      112677
20  2022-07-14 00:00       2974      115651
21  2022-07-15 00:00       1955      117606
22  2022-07-16 00:00       2474      120080
23  2022-07-17 00:00       2539      122619
24  2022-07-18 00:00       3260      125879
```